# Intellij Git Clone Issue

Tags: node.js, windows, git, intellij-idea, ssh

I'm using Intellij 2016.2.15 on Windows to code on a nodejs project.
Everything worked fined, I could work with git easily until the git server was reformated and the ssh key changed. I used the git console to add the keys to .ssh/known_hosts, I changed the intellij git option from "built-in" to "native". I reinstalled intellij, reinstalled git, delete every temporary files. I don't know what to do to make the connection work again.
Note that if I use the git console to do "git pull" for instance it works, but if I do the same on intellij I have a "Could not read from remote repository" error.
Does anyone have an IDEA (best joke 2016) ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: clone your repo newly from console and try to open it in intellij.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried and it doesn't work. Still cannot communicate with the server

Answer (score 0):

You can try **creating new ssh key pairs**, **update** your public key on git and try git again on command line. This should work.

If everything then works but intellij, it's because your private key requires a passphrase. You can try using a private key without passphrase (press enter when you are prompted to enter your passphrase). This solution might not be very secure though.